# How to repeat the conference name header to all the pages?

Tags: header-footer, ieeetran

My code is working to show the conference name header on the top?
But how do I repeat this conference name to all the pages?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\usepackage[T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\conf}[1]{%
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{% default title page headers, no footers
\def\@oddhead{\parbox[b]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\headerbox-\columnsep}{\centering \@IEEEheaderstyle #1}}%
\let\@evenhead\@empty
\def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}% 
\let\@evenfoot\@empty}}
\newcommand{\mycopyrightnotice}{\footnotesize 979-8-3503-3324-4/23/\$31.00 $\copyright$ 2023 IEEE\hfill}

\makeatother

%------conference Name-------%
\conf{\large{2023 International Conference on Circuit Power and Computing Technologies (ICCPCT)
}}

\begin{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome, @kze! My question is: *why*? Use the style they provide you, and focus on content. If the IEEE conference in question decided that the conference has to appear only on the title page, that's their call, not your... (this is one of the points in using LaTeX at all, separating format from content).